# Converting Dictionary<string, string> into multiple 1D int[] arrays

Tags: c#

How can I convert a `dictionary<string, string>` into a number of one dimension integer array at runtime? For example,

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("one", "1,3,6,8");
dic.Add("two", "2,3,6,9");

dic.Add("n", "3,4,1,8");
```

The desired resulting arrays would be:

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] {1,3,6,8};
int[] arr2 = new int[] {2,3,6,9};

int[] arrn = new int[] {3,4,1,8};
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Well for there to be separate *variables*, you'll need to know all the numbers involved at compile-time. (You can't just generate more variables at execution time... and you really don't want to get into the business of working out the word representations of numbers.) At that point it's fairly easy though:

```
arr1 = ParseValues(dic["one"]);
arr2 = ParseValues(dic["two"]);
arr3 = ParseValues(dic["three"]);
// etc

static int[] ParseValues(string values)
{
    return values.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}
```

Note that this will fail with empty strings - if you need it to handle that (returning an empty array) you want:

```
return values.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(int.Parse)
             .ToArray();
```

EDIT: If you don't know how many values there will be, but you know they'll always be present with no gaps, you could have:

```
// This has to go as far as you need to cope with
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", ... };

List<int[]> arrays = words.TakeWhile(word => dic.ContainsKey(word))
                          .Select(word => dic[word].Split(',')
                                                   .Select(int.Parse)
                                                   .ToArray())
                          .ToList();
```

(Note that in this list, element 0 will correspond to "one" etc... it'll all be offset by one.)

Comment: I don't know the number of keys in the dictionary at compile time. How can I declare arbitrary numbers of arrays at run time?

Comment: @user1193665: You can't. You can declare a `List<int[]>` though, if you want. But you'll still need a way of converting from `int` to the word form, if the dictionary keys *really* are going to be "one", "two" etc.

Comment: @user1193665: See my edit for an example of creating a `List<int[]>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do with help of the *Linq*, something it like that:

```
  int[] arr1 = dic["one"].Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
  int[] arr2 = dic["two"].Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
  int[] arrn = dic["n"].Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = dic.Select(x => x.Value.Split(new[]{','})
                 .Select(y => int.Parse(y)))
                 .ToArray();
```

Output:

[image]

Now it's just a matter of assigning each value to your variables.

```
var arr1 = results[0];
var arr2 = results[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of arrays, instead of declaring many arrays.

```
List<int[]> arrays = dic.Values.Select(v => v.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray())
                        .ToList();
```

`arrays[0]` would be `1,3,6,8`